# Angular2 Dart - get child elements of component

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I have a component called `button-search` which has a dropdown with search options:

```
<button-search> 
    <item type="identifier">Identifier</item>
    <item type="title">Title</item>
    <item type="city">City</item>
    <item type="town">Town</item>
    <item type="address">Address</item>
    <item type="postal">Postal</item>
    <item type="divider"></item>
    <item type="clear">Clear Search</item>
</button-search>
```

The `item` component is not supposed to render anything directly and is rather for passing complex params into the `button-search` component so that the `button-search` component can render those dropdown items the way it should be rendered.

`Item` is defined as follow:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'item',
    template: '')
class Item {

    @Input() String type = "type-goes-here";

}
```

`ButtonSearch` is defined as follow:

```
@Component(
    selector: 'button-search',
    directives: const[Item],
    template: '''
       ... enormous template ...    
    ''')
class ButtonSearch {

    ButtonSearch(@ViewChildren(Item) QueryList<Item> items){

        print(items);

    }
}
```

Instead of seeing a list of 9 items being printed to the console, all I'm seeing is `[]`.

I've tried using a String param instead of an object, but it still gives me null.

```
ButtonSearch(@ViewChildren('item') QueryList<Item> items){
```

1. What am I missing to make `@ViewChildren` get all the items and print something other than `[]`
2. Is there something special that needs to be done to get the text between `<item>` and `</item>` or will `@ViewChild` work for that ?

**Update**: Changing the template to include `<ng-content></ng-content>`:

```
template: '''
          <ng-content></ng-content>
           ... enormous template ...    
        ''')
```

I can see the following being printed in the browser as part of the `button-search` component:

> Identifier, Title, City, Town, Address, Postal, Clear Search

So at least I know the page I'm on does have items in its `button-search` component.

Comment: Please check if the `Item` components get instantiated. You can't query for `Item` if the elements are not upgrade to actual Angular components.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be

```
@Component(
    selector: 'button-search',
    directives: const[Item],
    template: '''
       <ng-content></ng-content>
       ... enormous template ...    
    ''')
class ButtonSearch implements AfterContentInit{
    @ContentChildren(Item) QueryList<Item> items;

    ngAfterContentInit() {
        print(items);
    }    
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/35209681/217408

There is also the `@Query()` annotation which allows to constructor-inject references to child elements but it is marked deprecated.

**`<ng-content>`**
If you pass "content" as children to your component, then you can query them using `@ContentChildren()` instead of `@ViewChildren()`. If you want them to be displayed in the DOM you also need to add the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag as a target for the transclusion. You can also have multiple `<ng-content></ng-content>` tags where a `select=".someCssSelector"` can be used to transclude a subset of content at a specific target location. There should be only one `<ng-content></ng-content>` without the `select` attribute though. The first without `select` will target all content that doesn't match other selectors.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CmsdHpAnRZb42E8Hnh2j?p=preview)

Comment: I've got it exactly like that now and it's still printing `[]`

Comment: `print(items)` is still printing out `[]` and `print(items.length)` is printing out `0`, so the items are still not getting into the ButtonSearch class. What I'm trying to do is to get a Dart list representation of all the child items of type `Item` so that I can do `print(item.type)` and `print(item.content)` after which I'm expecting a list in my console of `identifier`, `title`, ..., `clear`
`<ng-content>` is printing out all the text inside the items, so at least I'm sure that the search button I'm looking at does have items.

Comment: [**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/CmsdHpAnRZb42E8Hnh2j?p=preview) in TypeScript, but should be easy to translate. Maybe you're missing the `Item` class in `directives` where you use it.

Comment: Ah, didn't know I had to add the `Item` directive in two places. That fixes it :-D

Comment: You only need it at one place to directives in your example. There is no need to add them to `directives` in  the `ButtonSearch` component.